# Conversion of type "interface {}" to another interface in a slice of type "interface {}" via reflection

Tags: go, slice

I have a slice of type `People`, I need to pass this slice to a function that gets the type "interface {}". The People type "implements" an interface called `HasCustomField`, but I can't do the type conversion within the function, as I am doing:

```
type HasCustomField interface {
    GetCustomField() map[string]interface{}
}

type People struct {    
    Name string
    customField map[string]interface{}
}

func (c *People) GetCustomField() map[string]interface{} {
    if c.customField == nil {
        c.customField = make(map[string]interface{})
    }
    return c.customField
}

func main() {
    users := []People{{Name:"Teste"},{Name:"Mizael"}}
    ProcessCustomField(&users)
}

func ProcessCustomField(list interface{}) {
    if list != nil {
        listVal := reflect.ValueOf(list).Elem()

        if listVal.Kind() == reflect.Slice {

             for i:=0; i<listVal.Len(); i++ {
                 valueReflect := listVal.Index(i).Interface()
                 objValueFinal, ok := valueReflect.(HasCustomField)

                 if ok {
                    fmt.Println("OK")
                } else {
                    fmt.Println("NAO OK")
                }
        }
}
```

The result is always "Not OK", I can not do the conversion, I tried several other ways too, including calling the method `GetCustomField()` via reflection, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Your reflection won't work because it expects a slice, but you're passing a pointer to a slice. Don't do that. There's almost never a reason to use a pointer to a slice in Go.

Comment: Second, you should probably avoid reflection all together, and use a type assertion or another approach.

Comment: Right, but this is not the problem, iLoveReflection answered correctly, the problem was there.

Comment: Yes, he pointed out the exact same problem I did. So yes, that was the problem. He just gave a different, more complex, and less desirable way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GetCustomField` method is on the pointer receiver `*People`, but the slice contains `People` values. Take the address of slice element to use the pointer receiver:

```
valueReflect := listVal.Index(i).Addr().Interface()  // <-- Addr()
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5qu9gp6qEWm)

Bonus simplification: Use slice argument instead of pointer to slice.

```
ProcessCustomField(users) // <-- do not take addr here
...

listVal := reflect.ValueOf(list) <-- do not call Elem() here
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vudZvXb6uWB).